# Selenium waitForPageToLoad end condition

Tags: java, browser, selenium, pageload

I have a java selenium script where I am making a call to `com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.waitForPageToLoad(String)`. Which condition in the browser is selenium waiting for that will tell it that the page is done loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is waiting for a `pageLoad` event to be fired by the browser. If you look in the source for selenium, I think the logic for `waitForPageToLoad` can be found in [selenium-browserbot.js](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js?name=selenium-2.26.0).

Comment: Is this true for earlier version of IE (6 and 7)

Comment: AFAIK... I haven't noticed Selenium having different behavior based on the version of IE.